# How can I set a resolution restriction on my PHP uploader?

Tags: php, upload, max, resolution

I want to set a max picture resolution on my PHP upload button. I currently have it so that only JPEG, PNG and GIF files can be uploaded, and the max file size is 1MB. It works great but I would like it to have a maximum resolution restriction. Thanks!

Comment: Just use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/getimagesize) to check the image dimensions after the file has been uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use getimagesize() in PHP to read the uploaded file dimensions, but only after the upload has been completed.

Comment: Well, I want it to check before it's uploaded, so it can give an error saying it's too large. I don't know if this is possible though :/

Comment: That's not really possible. You might be able to do it with JavaScript or Flash but it won't have good browser support but I am not sure about those options.